# Validation error message is not shown when using listBox in ActiveField

Tags: yii2

I have a piece of the following code:

```
form->field($website, 'clients_id', [
          'template' => "{label}<div class='col-md-9'>{input}</div>\n{hint}\n{error}"
        ])
        ->listBox($dataList, [
                'data-placeholder' =>'Choose one..', 
                'class'            => 'select-select2',
                'style'            => 'width: 100%',
                'id'               => 'example-select2' 
            ]) 
        ->label('Clients')
```

In website model still return error validation for "clients_id" field. but in view not show the error

Although in the develop tool I still see this tag

```
<div class="help-block help-block-error "></div>
```

--- UPDATE ---

in my model :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['domain', 'clients_id', 'online_date'], 'required'],
        [['online_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['active', 'clients_id'], 'integer'],
        [['domain'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

and when I print error validations

```
array(1) {["clients_id"]=> array(1) {[0]=> string(27) "Clients ID cannot be blank." }}
```

-- ActiveForm settings in view ---

```
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'      => 'web-form',
        'layout'  => 'horizontal',
        'options' => [
            'class'   => 'form-horizontal form-bordered',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'horizontalCssClasses' => [
                'label' => 'col-md-3 control-label',
            ],
        ],
    ]); 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the validation rules for this attribute. What kind of error returns after validation?

Comment: Thanks @arogachev. I have just updated question. Please review it

Comment: And show the settings of `ActiveForm` in view.

Comment: @arogachev Done. please review again. Thanks

Comment: Remove 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' in ActiveForm setting. it's working now

Comment: @hoangk add your solution as answer